# Вид сказуемого.

Tags: синтаксис

1.Да ты ему в подметки не годишься!
2.До субботы я тоже успел провиниться.
3.Они дали друг другу клятву верности.
Определите,пожалуйста,вид сказуемого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во всех трех предложениях использовано простое глагольное сказуемое. Здесь устойчивые выражения равны глаголу: в подметки не годишься = уступаешь ('хуже'), успел провиниться = провинился, дали клятву = поклялись.

Почему-то не получается у меня комментировать собственные ответы. Так что дополняю свой ответ. В именном сказуемом должно быть ИМЯ (существительное, прилагательное, числительное) или равное ему по смыслу слово, например, причастие. Во втором предложении слово УСПЕЛ не модальный глагол, потому что не несет значения возможности, способности, предрасположенности, желательности и под. Пожалуй, его можно классифицировать как фазовый. Да. Соглашусь, что второй случай - составное глагольное.

Comment: Согласен с Вами только по поводу третьего предложения.Мне же кажется,что устойчивые сочетания,как правило,являются составным именным сказуемым.
Во втором предложении слово "успел" имеет явный оттенок окончания действия.На мой взгляд,это модальный глагол. (помним,что в составном глагольном он также может обозначать начало,продолжение,конец,возможность,желание и необходимость совершения действия.)

Comment: Главное слово в устойчивом сочетании - глагол (не годишься), следовательно, olsa права - сказуемое простое глагольное.